# Convert string into date time in python

Tags: python

I have a datetime string in the form of a string as:

```
20120808111051
```

How do i convert this string as the datetime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I detail:

```
import datetime

s = "20120808111051"
parsed_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent Python versions you can use the function strptime:

```
http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime
```

You can also do this in older Python versions:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = '20120808111051'
print datetime(int(d[0:4]), int(d[4:6]), int(d[6:8]), int(d[8:10]), int(d[10:12]), int(d[12:14]))
```

Comment: You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` as well.

Comment: As far as i know Python 2.4 doesn't provide strptime function. But i'm not sure which is the first version providing this function.

Comment: I would preferably use `datetime(*[int(_) for _ in struct.unpack("4s2s2s2s2s2s", d)])
` instead of slicing, but that's just personal preference

Answer (score 1):

You need datetime.strptime: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20120808111051', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 11, 10, 51)
```

Please note that I just guessed the format of the string you posted (i.e. the `0808` is month-day, or day-month?), you would have to know that.

Comment: It must be month-day. Day-month would not make any sense, there is only _one_ completely ass-backwards date format, which is the one with the weird separator, `/` :)